# Verlangt das Verb "übergehen" die Präposition "an" oder "in"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-case

> Ergänzend fügte er seiner Theorie vom Freigeld die des Freilands hinzu. Freiland war in seinen Augen Land, das **an** die Gesellschaft übergeht und dem Privatbesitz entzogen wird.

Answer (score 3):

Das kommt darauf an, was man ausdrücken will.

"Etwas geht **an** jemanden über" drückt den Wechsel der Kontrolle oder Verantwortung aus:

> Das Eigentum geht an den Kunden erst nach vollständiger Zahlung des für die konkrete Ware geschuldeten Entgelts über.
>
> Mit dem 1. Juli 2016 ging der Vorsitz der Europaministerkonferenz (EMK) von Hessen auf Mecklenburg-Vorpommern über.

"Etwas geht **in** etwas über" meint eine fließende Änderung eines Zustands oder dass etwas Teil von etwas anderem wird:

> Lediglich der Datenträger, auf dem sich die Software befindet, geht in Ihr Eigentum über.
>
> Wetterbericht: Schnee geht teils in Regen über und es besteht örtlich Glatteisgefahr.

Daneben hat das trennbare Verb *übergehen* noch weitere Bedeutungen, siehe z.B. beim [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/uebergehen_wechseln_verwandeln), für die z.T. auch die Präpositionen *zu* und *auf* in Frage kommen. Außerdem gibt es auch noch das untrennbare Verb *übergehen* ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/uebergehen_ignorieren_vorbeigehen)).

Im Beispiel aus der Frage ist also *an* richtig: Freiland ist Land, das unter die Verfügung der Gesellschaft kommt. Man könnte den Satz umformulieren, so dass *in* verwendet wird:

> Freiland war in seinen Augen Land, das in den Besitz der Gesellschaft übergeht und dem Privatbesitz entzogen wird.

Hier ist *in* richtig, weil das Land Teil eines (wahrscheinlich) größeren Besitzes wird.

Answer (score 0):

Sowohl als auch.
Etwas übergeht "an" jemanden.
Etwas übergeht "in" den Besitz von jemandem.

An sich ist "an" die Normalform. Übergeht es jedoch an etwas, das zu einem Ding oder einer Person gehört, wandelt es sich in "in". (EDIT: nicht notwendigerweise)

Bsp.:
Ich übergebe es in deine Obhut.
Ich übergab es in ihre Arme.

Ich übergebe es an den Postboten.
Ich übergebe es an den Staat.

Ich übergebe es "in" den Besitz des Postbotens.

Comment: oder wohl die am häufigsten gehörte Wendung: in Hände der Polizei.

Comment: @Albrecht Hügli, in *die* Hände der Polizei.

Comment: Wer hat das "die" geklaut???

Comment: Keine Ahnung, aber wir sollten ihn in DIE Hände der Polizei übergeben ^^

Comment: Ich halte die Unterscheidung von *geht über* und *übergeht* für bedeutsam und würde keines der Beispiele aus dem ersten Absatz so schreiben.

Comment: Downvote: die beiden Beispiele mit "Etwas übergeht ..." sind falsch, weil _übergehen_ im Kontext der Frage ein trennbares Verb ist. "An" als Normalform: davon zu sprechen, ist angesichts der vielen Bedeutungen des Wortes fragwürdig. Aber wenn schon, dann eher "in", denn weder Duden noch DWDS geben Beispiele mit _an_. Und die anderen Beispiele verwenden mit _übergeben_ ein anderes Verb.

Comment: Warum sind deine Beispiele mit übergeben, die Frage aber über übergehen?